# Endless page update in the browser (javascript)

Tags: javascript, cycle

```js
<script language="javascript">
<!--
writeCookie();

function writeCookie()
{
var today = new Date();
var the_date = new Date("December 31, 2023");
var the_cookie_date = the_date.toGMTString();
var the_cookie = "users_resolution="+ screen.width +"x"+ screen.height;
var the_cookie = the_cookie + ";expires=" + the_cookie_date;
document.cookie=the_cookie

location = 'screen.php';
}
//-->
</script>
```

This script detects screen resolution. If I turn "on" blocking cookies in browser, I get a "mini ddos", an endless update site page screen.php. How to get out of this situation?

Comment: Your `writeCookie` function does `location = 'screen.php'`, thus reloading the page.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is called on page load and always refreshes the page. You have no conditional statement to prevent an infinite loop.

To make things clearer, this is what is happening.

**Step 1)** Page is loaded

**Step 2)** Your function is called

**Step 3)** function refreshes the page. We're back to Step 1.

Comment: I perfectly understand that. But how do I make the javascript did not write a cookie in the browser if they are disabled in him?

Comment: @user110374 I think you're asking... "how you would store a cookie in a browser which has them disabled?". You cannot.